# libvirt doesn't create virtqemud-sock on macos

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I've installed qemu and libvirt on macos big sur with m1 using macports. When i've tried install libvirt with homebrew, it was broken (asked /proc/cpuinfo, lol). Libvirt started as daemon, i've got **libvirt-sock** on unix-socket directory, but have no **virtqemud-sock**.

Actions (all with sudo):

`port install qemu`

`port install libvirt`

`virsh -c qemu:///system`

Result:

`error: unable to connect to socket «/opt/local/var/run/libvirt/virtqemud-sock»: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

> Libvirt started as daemon, i've got libvirt-sock on unix-socket directory, but have no virtqemud-sock.

Libvirt has two ways to running - the monolithic daemon (`libvirtd`) is the traditional approach and the modular daemons (`virt${XXXX}d` for varying ${XXXX}) is the new way. The libvirt client here is attempting to connect to the modular daemon `virtqemud`, but it seems like you've started the monolithic `libvirtd`

More guidance can be found at

https://libvirt.org/daemons.html
https://libvirt.org/uri.html#mode-parameter